# Attempting to make countdown timer with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to make a clock using python's Tkinter. It works but not in the way I intended. Once the user enters the amount of time that needs to be counted down from, the action is performed but the actual countdown isn't being shown. I would like for the user to have the ability to watch the numbers go all the way until 0. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import time
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()


def countdown(t):
    ts = int(t)
    while ts > 0:
        timer = Label(timerFrame, text = ts)
        ts-=1
        timer.pack()
        time.sleep(1)
        if ts ==0:
            timer.destroy()
            completeTimer = Label(timerFrame, text="Time is complete")
            completeTimer.pack()


timerFrame = LabelFrame(root, padx=50, pady=50, bd=0)


timerFrameText = Label(timerFrame, 
    text="Enter time in seconds for countdown",
    font=("Arial", 20, "bold")
)
countdownBox= Entry(timerFrame, bd=3)

submitCountdown = Button(timerFrame, 
    padx=5, 
    pady=5, 
    text="Submit", 
    font=("Arial", 20),
    command= lambda:countdown(countdownBox.get())
   )


timerFrame.pack()


timerFrameText.pack()
countdownBox.pack()
submitCountdown.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: A quick fix would be to say `root.update()` after `time.sleep()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one I've implemented [Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). This allows you to run threads or let's say processes **synchronously**. In creating GUI applications and such as timers or any other program that needs to be run all at the same time it's really important that to learn [Multithreading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) and [MultiProcessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). It's a really huge factor in software development.

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import threading
root = Tk()


def cd(timer_label_obj,ts):
    while ts > 0:
        timer_label_obj.config(text=ts)
        ts-=1
        timer_label_obj.pack()
        time.sleep(1)
        if ts ==0:
            timer_label_obj.destroy()
            completeTimer = Label(timerFrame, text="Time is complete")
            completeTimer.pack()

def countdown(t):
    timer = Label(timerFrame)
    ts = int(t)
    th = threading.Thread(target=cd,args=[timer,ts])
    th.start()


timerFrame = LabelFrame(root, padx=50, pady=50, bd=0)


timerFrameText = Label(timerFrame, 
    text="Enter time in seconds for countdown",
    font=("Arial", 20, "bold")
)
countdownBox= Entry(timerFrame, bd=3)


submitCountdown = Button(timerFrame, 
    padx=5, 
    pady=5, 
    text="Submit", 
    font=("Arial", 20),
    command= lambda:countdown(countdownBox.get())
   )




timerFrame.pack()


timerFrameText.pack()
countdownBox.pack()
submitCountdown.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is perfect. I will definitely perform more research on threading.

Comment: You'll find it useful soon especially when you're dealing or creating an application that has a large scope in it :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe adding some kind of print statement with your ts value will help. Never used tkinter, but it looks like you only print when it finishes count down. Or try to print ts as a string like in a normal print statment:

```
print("current count %s" %ts)
```

Comment: The problem of OP is that the GUI freezes and does not show the output in the window, not in the console

Comment: Cool Cloud, your answer worked. Thank you very much.